# Проблема с автовключением службы bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth

Добавил скрипт автозапуска вот по этой [инструкции](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=300009.msg2350008#msg2350008)

И ничего... Проблема в том, что bluetooth автоматом никогда не запускается((( Только после такой команды: `sudo service bluetooth start`, в иных случаях не хочет пахать(

Добавил данную команду в [автозапуск по инструкции](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=300009.msg2350008#msg2350008), только сделал команду для запуска, но это не помогло(

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы автоматически подключалась эта служба?

Скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите содержимое /etc/rc.local

Comment: @DenisE, там пусто(можете скрин посмотреть)

Comment: в настройках переключатель блютус поставь в положение включенно

Comment: @eri, когда ставлю в положение включено - ничего не меняется. Только после `sudo service bluetooth start` всё начинает работать и запускаться....(в скринах добавил)

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth` тогда

Comment: @eri, спасибо))) Заработало

Comment: @eri, напишите ответ и я его приму через полчаcика 

Comment: а, у тебя кали - там наверное не доделали чтото. bluetooth у меня запускалась сама при включении переключателя в настройках в арче и дебиане.

Comment: @eri, да, у меня кали) Дело в том, что если указать что кали, то много людей сразу пишут: "Зачем тебе кали, ламер недоделанный?" ну и тд

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Службы с 16ого года почти во всех дистрибутивах можно включить через `systemctl`

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```